# Diode Insertion loss vs frequency

Tags: diodes, ltspice, simulation, datasheet, spice

I am referring this [document](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-AN_1809_PL32_1810_172154_PIN%20diodes%20in%20RF%20sw%20applications-AN-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d46265f064ff016643e2bc241042#:%7E:text=Infineon%20PIN%20diodes%20are%20ideal%20for%20a%20wide,They%20are%20offered%20in%20industry-standard%200201%20and%200402) for measuring
insertion loss of the diode in SPST configuration initially. As mentioned in Pg.No 7 circuit and using BOM given [image: Schematic]

Expected Result
[image: Plot]

I simulated using LTSpice

[image: LTSpice]

Is my measurement correct, Since expected plot has y-axis as S21 (dB) (I am assuming output w.r.t input). I measured V(OUT,IN)/V(IN,VOUT). What is the right way to measure this parameter ?

Comment: The transfer function is `OUTPUT / INPUT`, so it's `V(out)/V(in)` (for S21, or the forward voltage gain). If your input is `AC 1`, then all you need is `V(out)`. Also, you used a 50 Ohm terminating resistance, but not at the input. And simply because you have a model for a diode it doesn't mean that the diode will behave as expected -- you need to test the validity of the model, first.

Comment: Can you suggest me any diode/ diode model for the test. How do we judge input and output resistance by datasheet (insertion loss s frequency plots ?

Comment: At those frequencies you're looking at S-parameters specifically built for diodes. Check the manufacturer's datasheets or models.

Comment: @Pai The `README.TXT` for [that model download](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/BAR63_02L_spice_spar.zip?fileId=db3a304313d846880113deba78810417) is explicit in saying you need to add the package parasitics (found in an accompanying text file).  You seem to only have used the `D310.TXT` without the additional package components required for modeling above 100MHz.